# How can i replace the character 'O' by '0' in SAS without SQL?

Tags: replace, sas

I want to replace the character 'O' (capital O) by '0' (zero), but i have this character in different numbers.

Exemple:
in my dataset i have the number 8OO, 9O, 1O1, etc. and i need to change it for all of the O's.

Thank you!

Comment: How many variables? Why not SQL? Do you want to convert the character variable to a numeric variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TRANSLATE](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p05ww22zp7lcg3n1bjk7v93tscyo.htm) function

From the docs:

TRANSLATE(source, to-1, from-1 <, ...to-n, from-n>)

```
data want;
set have;

*replaces letter O with 0;
newVariable = translate(oldVariable, "0", "O");
*converts values from newVariable to a numeric value;
newVarnum = input(newVariable, 8.);

run;
```

Comment: Does 8 mean that the observation has 8 letters/character?

Comment: `8.` is the informat you want the INPUT() function to use.  It will use only the first 8 characters of NEWVARIABLE.  Note that the INPUT() function does not care if the width you use on the informat is longer than the string you are asking it to read. So just use `32.` as your default informat for converting strings to numbers since 32 is the widest value the informat supports.

Comment: NewVarNum line is to convert the variable to a numeric type, rather than character. That isn't really part of your question but what I'm guessing is your next step so I included it. You may need to modify that part based on your actual requirements and needs.